# PHPUnit: How to run only tests in classes that end with Test?

Tags: php, phpunit

## Issue Description

I use a configuration to run all tests in a directory

**phpunit-config.xml**

```xml
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="all">
      <directory>./tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

There are multiple classes in some files (i.e. it is not following PSR, see note at the bottom) that may extend a `*Test` class, but should not be run. Their name does not end with `Test`. For example `ExampleHelper`:

**tests/AllTest.php**

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
  public function testShouldRun(): void
  {
    $this->assertSame(0, 0);
  }
}

final class ExampleHelper extends ExampleTest
{
  public function testShouldNotBeExecuted(): void
  {
    $this->assertSame(0, 1);
  }
}
```

As the methods imply, `ExampleTest` should be executed, but `ExampleHelper` should not be executed.

## Reprodcution

### Directory structure

```
├── Dockerfile
├── bootstrap.php
├── docker-compose.yml
├── phpunit-config.xml
└── tests
    └── AllTest.php
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 php:7.4
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y git zip libzip-dev
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
WORKDIR /app
RUN composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:9.5.10
```

#### bootstrap.php

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build: ./
    image: phpunit-test
    command: ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit-config.xml
    volumes:
      - ./bootstrap.php:/app/bootstrap.php
      - ./phpunit-config.xml:/app/phpunit-config.xml
      - ./tests:/app/tests
```

### Run

```
docker-compose build && docker-compose up
```

#### Actual Output

```
...
app_1  | There was 1 failure:
app_1  | 
app_1  | 1) ExampleHelper::testShouldNotBeExecuted
app_1  | Failed asserting that 1 is identical to 0.
app_1  | 
app_1  | /app/tests/AllTest.php:16
app_1  | 
app_1  | FAILURES!
app_1  | Tests: 3, Assertions: 3, Failures: 1.
```

#### Expected Output

```
...
app_1  | OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

---

**Edit:** The actual project is a big old code base. Since multiple classes are in some files, it is not following PSR. This should be changed in the long run, but is too costly at the moment. I'm looking for a solution that requires minimal change to the existing files, e.g. only the configuration.

Btw. `ExampleHelper` was not run in an earlier version of PHPUnit. I guess it was 4.8.

Comment: Generally, you wouldn't have multiple classes in the same file.

Comment: @NigelRen I know, but you sometimes have to work with what you get ;)

Comment: This is really strange that your `ExampleHelper extends ExampleTest`. What is the purpose of the `ExampleHelper` class if it does not contain any test ?

Comment: As for how to run only the classes you want, you can write a custom [`TestSuiteLoader`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Runner/TestSuiteLoader.php) and use it thanks to the [`testSuiteLoaderClass`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html) configuration.

Comment: @homer Thanks, this looks promising. The use case is hard to explain, since it is kind of a hack. The `ExampleHelper` instance is actually created in a test method of `ExampleTest`, which calls a test method of `ExampleHelper`. `ExampleHelper` overwrites some methods of `ExampleTest` used by the test method. To make it even more complicated, the test methods are inherited from traits that use a `TestTemplate` class that defines the actual tests and may query data from the actual test class using methods that follow a certain naming convention and may  override defaults of the template.

Comment: @maiermic in fact that does not look trivial at all, maybe the architecture need to be re-thinked.

Comment: @homer I would argue 100% that this author needs to switch to Laravel or Symfony, but not a bare PHP implementation... Also, author, if you cannot change the current implementation (multiple classes per file), please write that in your question, as that is not correct at all, you are not following PSR. If this is based on a workplace and you cannot do that change, it is important that you share that information...

Comment: @matiaslauriti They may be using a framework, I do agree on the 1 file per class though. That said @maiermic there is an easier solution, PHPUnit runs only `public function test*` as test, so all you can do is just rename the wrongly named functions.

Comment: @homer or any method that has `@test` as a PHPDoc

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes but the issue is that PHPUnit runs methods that he should not. It is not  to run additional tests.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I've updated the description about being not PSR conform.

Answer (score 1):

There exists at least 2 solutions to your issue.

### 1. Rename non-test functions

The [PHPUnit's doc](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) states that:

> The tests are public methods that are named `test*`

So changing the visibility of your non-test functions, or renaming them to not start with `test` should solve your issue: those functions will not be automatically run by PHPUnit.

### 2. Write a custom `TestSuiteLoader`

If the solution 1 do not fulfill your needs you can still write a custom [`TestSuiteLoader`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Runner/TestSuiteLoader.php) and declare it in the configuration with the [`testSuiteLoaderClass`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html#the-testsuiteloaderclass-attribute) (or the [`testSuiteLoaderFile`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html#the-testsuiteloaderfile-attribute)) configuration attribute.

Comment: Regarding solution 1: The issue is that `ExampleHelper extends ExampleTest` and `ExampleTest` defines test methods that should be run for `ExampleTest`, but not in the sub-class `ExampleHelper`, i.e. it is not possible to rename those test.